# How can I compile mixare project, using Intellij Idea instead of eclipse?

Tags: java, android

[There is](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/wiki/GettingStarted) an instruction that tells how to build a project using Eclipse, but I can't repeat it in the Intellij Idea.
I can't import mixarelib correctly. =\

Comment: hi shishkin, how did you do it? can you explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mixarelib project is in a subfolder of the main project (i.e. part of your working copy). Try to add it as a separate project in your IDE and mark it as a "Library" project (that is part of the ADT workflow) and use it as dependency for the main project.